# Invalidating Devise user session identifier after password update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

**Scenario:** As an Administrator I need to invalidate a user's session (log them out) after I update the user's password. This is in accordance with best practices as per https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#Renew_the_Session_ID_After_Any_Privilege_Level_Change

I am using Devise and I saw here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45756884/664675 there is a config to log the user out: `config.sign_in_after_reset_password = false`

However, I have enabled this config in my `devise.rb` but the user remains logged in. Not sure why that is?

I am also using Redis as the `session_store`

```
  Example::Application.config.session_store :cache_store, 
    key: '_example_session', 
    secure: true
```

Is it feasible to delete the particular user's session store from Redis upon Password reset by the Administrator? And if so how could I find their particular session key within Redis?

Comment: Hmm but after reading this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243197/664675 I may have the wrong impression of the session mechanism. How does `sign_in_after_reset_password = false`work then though?

Comment: how did you update user's password ?

Comment: @LamPhan via a controller action accessible by an Administrator who can change the user's pass. Eventually ends up calling this on the User model:

```
    password = password
    password_confirmation = password
    valid?
    if errors.key?(:password)
      false
    else
      save(validate: false)
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the flag `sign_in_after_reset_password` does not relate to `logout` user at all, `sign_in_after_reset_password = false` imply that in case a user update his account password by himself then do not automatically sign-in his account again, and that logic happen only on [PasswordsController#update](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L33).
So you as admin try to change password of another user in a custom controller, of course it's not logout user no matter the value of `sign_in_after_reset_password` is.

`devise` use gem `warden` to `logout` user (in other word: destroy user session) and `warden` base on `request session` not base on `database`, that mean there's no way an admin can get another user's session to reset, so you can not force logout another user by only `devise`, you need to handle this feature outside devise (such as add `session` to `user` table or a devise hook something like [timeoutable](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb))

reference: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5262

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected but wanted a second opinion. I did run across your reference during my research.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the setting `sign_in_after_change_password` which you should set to `false` (it defaults to `true`). The method has a slightly confusing name – it means "should we sign the user in after changing their password" instead of "should the user have to sign in after changing their password".

References:

- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/lib/devise.rb#L296-L298
- https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/c82e4cf47b02002b2fd7ca31d441cf1043fc634c/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L163-L167